# I want to read from excel .xlsx file with java's library Apache Poi, but I can't fix an error, code does not compile

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

## **I was following a video on youtube for reading an excel file with apache poi, but it appears that my code does not compile, while I am doing exactly as the youtube guy**

Writing part works well but I am still copying it, as I think it may interrupt with reading part. Also I am sharing a link of the video I am following on youtube.`

```
package amalyze;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;



public class Amalyze {

private static Workbook wbR;
private static Sheet sheetR;
private static FileInputStream fis;
private static FileOutputStream fos;
private static Row rowR;
private static Cell cellR;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception{


        //Reading part
        fis = new FileInputStream("./amzdata.xlsx");
        wbR = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        sheetR =wbR.getSheet("Sheet1");







        // Writing Part
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstExcelSheet");
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(7);
        cell.setCellValue("str");
        workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("Excelamz.xls"));
        workbook.close();





    }

}
```

[Snippet of error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKeyf.png)
[Tutorial Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6xZgW_G6qA&t=244s)

Comment: Right now I don't understand your problem

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing the xmlbeans transitive dependency.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans

I would recommend using Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies.

Comment: Hey, can you please explain what this transitive dependencies are used for, and how am I supposed to use them.

Comment: A transitive dependency is a dependency of a dependency. In your case the Apache POI library depends on the xmlbeans library. You can either add all those jars in the correct versions manually to your classpath or you can use a tool such as Maven or Gradle to do it for you. I would strongly recommend the latter.